# Destroy a Jquery function when media query changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, enquire.js

Hope you can help me out.

I have searched through the forums, I guess this one is a special case.

The project I am building are powered with media queries (Responsive), I have 3 columns, sometimes 4 to needs to be in **equal height**. I have developed a script in Jquery which works great. See below

```
var maxHeight = 0;
function setHeight(column) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        column = $(column);
        column.each(function () {
            if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        });

        column.height(maxHeight);
    });
}

setHeight('.package-container .package-3');
```

But when I am going to mobile version, **below 767px**, how do I **destroy** this **setHeight()** function without having to refresh the page.

Other alternative, I can do this below using enquire.js, javascript media query but I could not get it to work without having to refresh if I go straight from Desktop/tablet to mobile. Like this below

```
enquire.register("(max-width:767px)", {
    match : function() {
        setHeight(null);
    }
}).listen();
```

Comment: Can't you just not call `setHeight` when you go below 767px?

Comment: Think about it, in mobile version: Columns does not exist, everything is stacked on top of each other.

Comment: At the mean time, CSS queries helped me out.

`@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .package-content {
      height: 100% !important;
   }
}`

Comment: Is the setHeight-function called on window resize-event, or just once at load?

Comment: Loaded once with $(window).load(), I could try $(window).resize() with conditionals. Thanks for the head up.

The reason I am using $(window).load() because it gives me an accurate measurement after all images downloads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do in a mobile first approach, you dont need to worry about "destroy" anything simple set the height to auto:

```
enquire.register("screen and (min-width : 768px)", {
    match : function() {
        // set equal height for columns
        setHeight('.package-container .package-3');
    },
    unmatch : function() {
        // set auto height
        $('.package-container .package-3').height("auto");
    }
}).listen();
```

Comment: hey John, thanks for helping with some of the enquire questions :) Saves me having to answer, which is always nice!